# JavaFX TableView: update a value from another cell

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a class BillingController it contains tableview.i want to update a qty cell also automatically update a amount cell.how to update a amount cell in tableview
  Here is code:

```
 colSno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BillingModel,String>("s_no"));
    colSno.setPrefWidth( 100 );

    colItem.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<BillingModel,String>("item_name")
    );
    colItem.setPrefWidth( 250 );
    colQty.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<BillingModel,String>("quantity")
    );
    colQty.setPrefWidth( 100 );
    tableBill.setEditable( true );
    javafx.util.Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
            new javafx.util.Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    return new EditingCell();
                }
            };
    colQty.setCellFactory(cellFactory);




    colRate.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<BillingModel,String>("rate")
    );
    colRate.setPrefWidth( 100 );
    colAmount.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<BillingModel,String>("amount")
    );

    colAmount.setPrefWidth( 120 );

    colAmount.setCellFactory(new javafx.util.Callback<TableColumn<BillingModel,String>, TableCell<BillingModel,String>>()
    {
        @Override
        public TableCell<BillingModel, String> call(
                TableColumn<BillingModel, String> param)
        {
            return new TableCell<BillingModel, String>()
            {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                {
                    if (!empty)
                    {

                        int currentIndex = indexProperty()
                                .getValue() < 0 ? 0
                                : indexProperty().getValue();
                        String type = param
                                .getTableView().getItems()
                                .get(currentIndex).quantity;

                        BillingModel billingModel = modelObservableList.get(currentIndex);
                        System.out.println("chenged item---->"+billingModel.getQuantity());
                        setText(item);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected boolean isItemChanged(String oldItem, String newItem) {
                    return super.isItemChanged(oldItem, newItem);
                }


            };
        }
    });
```

and editing table cell is

```
public class EditingCell extends TableCell<BillingModel, String> {
private TextField textField;
public EditingCell() {
}
@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    if (textField == null) {
        createTextField();
    }
    setGraphic(textField);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();
    setText((String) getItem());
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
}


@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(getString());
            }
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        } else {
            setText(getString());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }
}
private void createTextField() {
    textField = new TextField(getString());
    textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
    textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                int index = getTableRow().getIndex();
                BillingModel billingModel = getTableView().getItems().get(index);
                billingModel.setQuantity(textField.getText());
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
                TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(!t.isShiftDown());
                if (nextColumn != null) {
                    getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), nextColumn);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (!newValue && textField != null) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        }
    });
}
private String getString() {
    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
}
/**
 *
 * @param forward true gets the column to the right, false the column to the left of the current column
 * @return
 */
private TableColumn<BillingModel, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
    List<TableColumn<BillingModel, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TableColumn<BillingModel, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
        columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
    }
    //There is no other column that supports editing.
    if (columns.size() < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    int currentIndex = columns.indexOf(getTableColumn());
    int nextIndex = currentIndex;
    if (forward) {
        nextIndex++;
        if (nextIndex > columns.size() - 1) {
            nextIndex = 0;
        }
    } else {
        nextIndex--;
        if (nextIndex < 0) {
            nextIndex = columns.size() - 1;
        }
    }
    return columns.get(nextIndex);
}

private List<TableColumn<BillingModel, ?>> getLeaves(TableColumn<BillingModel, ?> root) {
    List<TableColumn<BillingModel, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
        //We only want the leaves that are editable.
        if (root.isEditable()) {
            columns.add(root);
        }
        return columns;
    } else {
        for (TableColumn<BillingModel, ?> column : root.getColumns()) {
            columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
        }
        return columns;
    }
}
```

}
how to update a another cell based on qty cell?
Any ideas on this would be much appreciated. :D

Thanks, Priya

Comment: dont dont dont dont ... it's __not__ the task of a cell to change the data in any way !!  Instead, use a editCommitHandler on the column

Comment: Thanks@kleopatra my problem sloved

Comment: kleopatra is known for her non-helping skills, so don't don't don't don't mind her. However, I would like to learn how you solved this issue. I have the same problem and I also want to do what you did! Any tips?